# What port should I run my Socket.IO server on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Is there any suggested ports to run Socket.IO servers on? Currently I run Socket.IO on ports 6001,6002, and 6003. However I find some people have trouble connecting to them so I was wondering if there are better ones to use.

Comment: I think you can use port 80 with socket.io and webserver at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

Unless socket.IO has some odd implementation you should be able to use the regular port 80 and 443 since you are connecting with a distinct protocol.

Comment: But isnt my webserver using port 80? It says "address in use" if I try to launch on port 80.

Comment: Sounds like you are running the websocket server separately. Depending on your server you should be able to configure it to instantiate a websocket handler (like socket.IO) and pass on ws requests to this handler. I've never done this with socket.IO but with other websocket handlers in express js.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing to lookout for is firewalls, so you should be reading this study about Socket.IO and firewalls: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Socket.IO-and-firewall-software

Comment: Link seems to be not working, or is linking to something else.